# how to change target framework to .NET Framework 4 from .NET Framework 4 Client Profile in cmd

Tags: azure, windows-services, azureservicebus

I am just trying to build windows service through cmd in virtual machine then this error is coming The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' how to fix it.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, please mark it.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Client Profile is a subset of the .NET Framework, I assume that ServiceBus is **not supported** in the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. More info about client profie, please refer to this [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/client-profile).

I assume that you use the [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) SDK, and we could get the answer from nuget [document](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus).

> Please note that this package requires **.Net Framework 4.5 Full Profile**.